# How to Uninstall reFIND boot manager completely in ubuntu LTS 20.04?

Tags: grub2, refind

I have recently installed reFIND boot manager in ubuntu LTS 20.04 and am unable to uninstall it completely. Please help me.

Comment: Simply install the boot manager you want. See `man -k grub`.

Comment: how ?? i mean, even if i do it like this will I get the files in the root folder which I get now ??